# Scrolling horizontally and vertically ListView WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I've couple of questions regarding scrolling ListView without using external ListView controls from other vendors (free or pay versions).

1. How to make 2 (or more) ListView bound together in the way that if i start scrolling one ListView the other one does exactly the same? Is it even possible to do with native 3.5 or 4.0 (when it's released) ListView?
2. When you try to scroll ListView right or left using the arrows on the scroll bar it's very very slow. For fast way you either have to grab the scroll and move it yourself or do jumps with it. Is there a way to make the left or right moving faster? A bit like down/up? (although i guess the speed is the same just the length to scroll is proportionally longer).

With regards,

MadBoy

Comment: Is this a WPF or Windows Forms listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use P/Invoke to make this work.  You'll find example code in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/70b4ae57-01b6-4708-9f38-7879916f8b18/).  It is for a ListBox, it will also work for ListView.  Use pinvoke.net to find the C# declaration for SendMessage.

I'm not aware of a fix for the scroll increment.  The SetScrollInfo API function doesn't allow setting the small step increment.

Comment: I'll try to use this. Never used P/Invoke before so might have some heavy trouble but if it's the only way i have no choice ;) Thanks.